# How do I make a number decrease by 5 every 20 seconds, and then display this number live?

Tags: javascript

How do I make a number (var is f) decrease by 5 every 20 seconds, and then display this number live? I am making a Hunger Games simulator to play live with my friends, and I want each tributes hunger to display live for them (all on separate devices). I want the hunger to decrease by 5 every 20 seconds. This is what I have tried:

```
    <h1>Hunger Games Tribute Status:</h1>
    <button onclick="startgame()">START GAME</button>
    <h5 id="hunger"></h5>
</body>
```

```
function startgame(){
var f = 200;
var intervalID = window.setInterval (foodcountdown(), 20000);
document.getElementById("hunger".innerHTML = f; }

function foodcountdown() {
var x=f-5;
var f=x;   }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to share you f variable, you should put it in the global scope

```
var f = 200; //moved

function startgame(){
  var intervalID = window.setInterval (foodcountdown(), 20000);
  document.getElementById("hunger").innerHTML = f; //corrected 
}

function foodcountdown() {
  f=f-5; //corrected
  document.getElementById("hunger").innerHTML = f; //added 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `setinterval(foodcountdown, 20000);` - There should not be `()`, you need to pass the function to the interval to let it execute it, not execute it yourself
2. `getElementById('hunger').innerHTML` - You need a `.` in front of `innerHTML`, not a `;` as you currently have
3. By using the keyword `var` in `var f = ...` inside your `foodcountdown` function, you are creating a local variable, and thus not affecting the one you want, declared in `startGame`. `f` needs to be accessible by both functions, make it global, or at least in the same upper scope
4. Your `intervalID` also needs to be accessible if you ever want to clear it
5. You're displaying the food count at the start of the game, but  never again

Here is a fixed demo:

```js
var f, intervalID;

function startgame() {
  f = 200; // Allows you to restart a game from the start
  clearInterval(intervalID); // In case a game was already started
  intervalID = setInterval(foodcountdown, 200); // changed to 200ms for the demo
  displayFoodCount();
}

function foodcountdown() {
  f -= 5;
  displayFoodCount();
  if (f <= 0) {
    clearInterval(intervalID);
    console.log('Game over!');
  }
}

function displayFoodCount() {
  document.getElementById("hunger").innerHTML = f;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hunger Games Tribute Status:</h1>
<button onclick="startgame()">START GAME</button>
<h5 id="hunger"></h5>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is working example. Move your *variables* and *DOM Selections* to the the top. And also you can use `innerText` instead of innerHTML if you don't going to insert HTML.

```
const hunger = document.getElementById("hunger");
const f = 200;

hunger.innerText = f;

function foodCountDown() {
 setInterval(function() {
   f -= 5
   hunger.innerText = f
 }, 20000)
}
```

Comment: where should I put this in my code?do I need to replace any function names from your answer?

Comment: You can put the variables inside the start game function. After that call foodCountDown() inside startGame()

Answer (score 0):

1. You should declare `f` as a global variable, outside the functions.
2. You should update the HTML element every time you decrease the value.
3. You should pass the function to `setInterval`, and not the result of the function.
4. You have a `;` before `innerHTML` instead of `.`.

So (I decreased the interval for the sample):

```js
var f, intervalID;

function startgame() {
  f = 200;
  intervalID = window.setInterval(foodcountdown, 2000);
}

function foodcountdown() {
  f = f - 5;
  document.getElementById("hunger").innerHTML = f;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hunger Games Tribute Status:</h1>
<button onclick="startgame()">START GAME</button>
<h5 id="hunger"></h5>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you are invoking your foodcountdown function instead of passing it in. Also you need to make sure that the startgame function is called when the DOM is loaded (maybe call it in the onload of the body).

```
var f = 200;
var interval;

function startgame() {
    interval = setInterval(foodcountdown, 20000);
}

function foodcountdown() {
    console.log(f);
    if (f <= 0) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
    document.getElementById("hunger").innerHTML = f;
    f -= 5;
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <body onload="startgame()">
        <div id="hunger"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Move the bulk of the logic inside the `setInterval` function and make sure to `return` the function if the timer reaches 0:

```js
function startgame() {
  let f = 200;
  document.getElementById("hunger").innerHTML = f;

  const intervalID = window.setInterval(() => {
    if (f === 0) return;

    f -= 5;
    document.getElementById("hunger").innerHTML = f;
  }, 500);
}
```

```html
<h1>Hunger Games Tribute Status:</h1>
<button onclick="startgame()">START GAME</button>
<h5 id="hunger"></h5>
```

(Shortened the time for demonstration.)

Comment: OP is attempting to pass a named function to `setInterval`. Why change it to an anonymous function? Seems like this will confuse the issue

Comment: 'How do I make a number (var is f) decrease by 5 every 20 seconds, and then display this number live?' this solves that issue and simplifies it into one function.